# Escape quotes contained within certain html tags

Tags: python, mysql

I've done a mysqldump of a large database, ~300MB. It has made an error though, it has not escaped any quotes contained in any `<o:p>...</o:p>` tags. Here's a sample:

```
...Text here\' escaped correctly, <o:p> But text in here isn't. </o:p> Out here all\'s well again...
```

Is it possible to write a script (preferably in Python, but I'll take anything!) that would be able to scan and fix these errors automatically? There's quite a lot of them and Notepad++ can't handle a file of that size very well...

Comment: It would be quite easy in Python I suppose. One hour or so, tops. I suggest that you make the script yourself because Python is really fun! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the "lines" your file is divided into are of reasonable lengths, and there are no binary sequences in it that "reading as text" would break, you can use `fileinput`'s handy "make believe I'm rewriting a file in place" functionality:

```
   import re
   import fileinput

   tagre = re.compile(r"<o:p>.*?</o:p>")
   def sub(mo):
     return mo.group().replace(r"'", r"\'")

   for line in fileinput.input('thefilename', inplace=True):
     print tagre.sub(sub, line),
```

If not, you'll have to simulate the "in-place rewriting" yourself, e.g. (oversimplified...):

```
   with open('thefilename', 'rb') as inf:
     with open('fixed', 'wb') as ouf:
       while True:
         b = inf.read(1024*1024)
         if not b: break
         ouf.write(tagre.sub(sub, b))
```

and then move `'fixed'` to take place of `'thefilename'` (either in code, or manually) if you need that filename to remain after the fixing.

This is oversimplified because one of the crucial `<o:p> ... </o:p>` parts might end up getting split between two successive megabyte "blocks" and therefore not identified (in the first example, I'm assuming each such part is always fully contained within a "line" -- if that's not the case then you should not use that code, but the following, anyway).  Fixing this requires, alas, more complicated code...:

```
   with open('thefilename', 'rb') as inf:
     with open('fixed', 'wb') as ouf:
       while True:
         b = getblock(inf)
         if not b: break
         ouf.write(tagre.sub(sub, b))
```

with e.g.

```
   partsofastartag = '<', '<o', '<o:', '<o:p'
   def getblock(inf):
     b = ''
     while True:
       newb = inf.read(1024 * 1024)
       if not newb: return b
       b += newb
       if any(b.endswith(p) for p in partsofastartag):
         continue
       if b.count('<o:p>') != b.count('</o:p>'):
         continue
       return b
```

As you see, this is pretty delicate code, and therefore, what with it being untested, I can't *know* that it is correct for your problem.  In particular, can there be cases of `<o:p>` that are NOT matched by a closing `</o:p>` or vice versa?  If so, then a call to `getblock` could end up returning the whole file in quite a costly way, and even the RE matching and substitution might backfire (the latter would also occur if SOME of the single-quotes in such tags are already properly escaped, but not all).

If you have at least a GB or so, avoiding the delicate issues with block division, at least, IS feasible, since everything should fit in memory, making the code much simpler:

```
   with open('thefilename', 'rb') as inf:
     with open('fixed', 'wb') as ouf:
         b = inf.read()
         ouf.write(tagre.sub(sub, b))
```

However, the other issues mentioned above (possible unbalanced opening/closing tags, etc) might remain -- only you can study your existing defective data and see if it affords such a reasonably simple approach at fixing!

Comment: Thanks, that worked great, all I need to do now is find all the other queries with unescaped quotes that don't have such a handy way of finding them...